# Matching two dataframe with differents number of rows inside a loop

Tags: r

I think my problem is not hard to solve without my data. I will like to perform a loop in R for this instead of doing it manually since the answer is not always 34 iterations, it can be more or less.

The dataframe "price" is absolutely huge (around 4 million rows by 20 columns) but does not change.

[image: price]

The dataframe "ihbm_hf"  is a lot smaller, 34 rows by 20 columns, but CHANGE based on another calculation.

[image: ihbm_hf]

The id for both dataframe are GVKEY, but I only want to keep the data in price for the GVKEY contained in "ihbm_hf" and store this data inside phbm_hfm1

This is the task I want to perform automatically.

```
 phbm_hf1 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[1] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf2 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[2] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf3 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[3] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf4 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[4] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf5 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[5] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf6 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[6] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf7 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[7] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf8 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[8] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf9 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[9] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf10 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[10] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf11 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[11] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf12 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[12] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf13 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[13] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf14 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[14] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf15 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[15] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf16 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[16] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf17 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[17] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf18 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[18] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf19 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[19] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf20 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[20] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf21 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[21] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf22 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[22] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf23 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[23] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf24 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[24] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf25 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[25] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf26 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[26] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf27 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[27] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf28 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[28] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf29 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[29] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf30 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[30] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf31 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[31] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf32 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[32] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf33 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[33] == price$gvkey),]
    phbm_hf34 <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[34] == price$gvkey),]

    phbm_hf <- rbind(phbm_hf1, phbm_hf2, phbm_hf3, phbm_hf4, 
               phbm_hf5, phbm_hf6, phbm_hf7, phbm_hf8, 
               phbm_hf9, phbm_hf10, phbm_hf11, phbm_hf12, 
               phbm_hf13, phbm_hf14, phbm_hf15, phbm_hf16, 
               phbm_hf17, phbm_hf18, phbm_hf19, phbm_hf20, 
               phbm_hf21, phbm_hf22, phbm_hf23, phbm_hf24, 
               phbm_hf25, phbm_hf26, phbm_hf27, phbm_hf28,
               phbm_hf29, phbm_hf30, phbm_hf31, phbm_hf32,
               phbm_hf33, phbm_hf34)
```

The resulting output is 98 369 rows by 20 columns.

[phbm_hf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLlCi.png)

It is exactly what I wanted. But since the rows number contained in ihbm_hf is not always 34 I can't use this code, it was working because I know the ihbm_hf's length at that particular moment was 34.

```
####since the length can be longer or shorter than 34    
l <- length(ihbm_hf$gvkey)

for(i in 1:l){

  phbm_hf  <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[i] == price$gvkey),]

  }
```

The problem with this code is that it only kept in phbm_hf the last observation (the 34th observations) and I have no idea how I can store them like I do manually in the long code inside a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data table format for speed
setDT(price)
setDT(ihbm_hf)

# filter price data
phbm_hf = price[GVKEY %in% ihbm_hf$GVKEY]
```

Comment: Perfect answer, this also slove another probleme with my "manual code" that I did not mention in the question! (data duplication caused by the same gvkey on different rows in ihbm_hf)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this, but I will point out the quick fix to your solution. The problem with your loop is you keep updating/overwriting the same variable (`phbn_hf`) with each iteration through the loop. You would need to store the result separately. One way would be in a vector, for example:

```
l <- length(ihbm_hf$gvkey)
phbn_hf <- rep(NA, l) # creates a vector of length l

for(i in 1:l){

   phbm_hf[i] <- price[which(ihbm_hf$gvkey[i] == price$gvkey),]

}
```